# Get Uri filepath of a .pdf file

Tags: android, pdf, uri, filepath

Hello am trying to get the real file path of a pdf  I select so that I can upload it to server.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_PDF_REQUEST_CODE) {getApplicationContext();
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            Uri uri = data.getData();
            auxFile = new File(uri.getPath());
            pdfPath = auxFile.getAbsolutePath();

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pdfPath,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();


        } else {
            // failed to select file
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question exactly? What is the problem?

Comment: Am getting  content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/614     and i cant upload it to the server

Comment: So what's wrong? What's the question?

Comment: The name of the file is admin.pdf , but am getting content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/‌​614 i want to get the real file so that i can upload it to server

Answer (score 0):

> i want to get the real file

There is no "real file". You did not show what you used to get this result, but presumably it was `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`. That, or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, are not limited to files on the filesystem that you can access. They can return a `Uri` that points to *anything that the content provider wants*: encrypted content, files in inaccessible locations, `BLOB` columns, content that needs to be downloaded, and so on. The user chooses the content, not you, and the user might choose from any of these types of sources.

> so that i can upload it to server

Find some HTTP API that supports uploading from a `Uri`.

Or, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, then find some HTTP API that supports uploading from an `InputStream`.

Or, use `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content, make a copy of that content to some temporary file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), upload from your temporary file, then delete the temporary file when the download is complete.

Comment: Oh okay ...may be i was getting something wrong but i have been able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fun getPath(uri: Uri): String? {
            val isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

            // DocumentProvider
            if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
                // ExternalStorageProvider
                if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
                    val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    val split = docId.split(":");
                    val type = split[0];

                    if ("primary".equals(type, true)) {
                        return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/" + split[1];
                    }
                    // TODO handle non-primary volumes
                }
                // DownloadsProvider
                else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {
                    val id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                    val contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));
                    return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                }
                // MediaProvider
                else
                    if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
                        val docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
                        val split = docId.split(":");
                        val type = split[0];
                        var contentUri: Uri? = null;
                        if ("image" == type) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("video" == type) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        } else if ("audio" == type) {
                            contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
                        }
                        val selection = "_id=?";
                        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(split[1])
                        return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
                    }
            }
            // MediaStore (and general)
            else if ("content".equals(uri.getScheme(), true)) {
                // Return the remote address
                if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
                    return uri.getLastPathSegment();
                return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
            }
            // File
            else if ("file".equals(uri.getScheme(), true)) {
                return uri.getPath();
            }
            return null;
        }

        fun getDataColumn(context: Context, uri: Uri?, selection: String?, selectionArgs: Array<String>?): String? {
            var cursor: Cursor? = null;
            val column = "_data";
            val projection = arrayOf(column);
            try {
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.getString(index);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
            return null;
        }

        fun isExternalStorageDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.externalstorage.documents" == uri.authority;
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is DownloadsProvider.
         */
        fun isDownloadsDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents" == uri.authority;
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is MediaProvider.
         */
        fun isMediaDocument(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.android.providers.media.documents" == uri.authority;
        }

        /**
         * @param uri The Uri to check.
         * @return Whether the Uri authority is Google Photos.
         */
        fun isGooglePhotosUri(uri: Uri): Boolean {
            return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content" == uri.authority;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved after copying that pdf file to cache directory
Please check the complete solution here:

```
public static final String DOCUMENTS_DIR = "documents";

if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

            if (id != null && id.startsWith("raw:")) {
                return id.substring(4);
            }

            String[] contentUriPrefixesToTry = new String[]{
                    "content://downloads/public_downloads",
                    "content://downloads/my_downloads"
            };

            for (String contentUriPrefix : contentUriPrefixesToTry) {
                Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Uri.parse(contentUriPrefix), Long.valueOf(id));
                try {
                    String path = getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
                    if (path != null) {
                        return path;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }

            // path could not be retrieved using ContentResolver, therefore copy file to accessible cache using streams
            String fileName = getFileName(context, uri);
            File cacheDir = getDocumentCacheDir(context);
            File file = generateFileName(fileName, cacheDir);
            String destinationPath = null;
            if (file != null) {
                destinationPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
                saveFileFromUri(context, uri, destinationPath);
            }

            return destinationPath;
        }

public static String getFileName(@NonNull Context context, Uri uri) {
    String mimeType = context.getContentResolver().getType(uri);
    String filename = null;

    if (mimeType == null && context != null) {
        String path = getPath(context, uri);
        if (path == null) {
            filename = getName(uri.toString());
        } else {
            File file = new File(path);
            filename = file.getName();
        }
    } else {
        Cursor returnCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        if (returnCursor != null) {
            int nameIndex = returnCursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME);
            returnCursor.moveToFirst();
            filename = returnCursor.getString(nameIndex);
            returnCursor.close();
        }
    }

    return filename;
}

public static String getName(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int index = filename.lastIndexOf('/');
    return filename.substring(index + 1);
}

public static File getDocumentCacheDir(@NonNull Context context) {
    File dir = new File(context.getCacheDir(), DOCUMENTS_DIR);
    if (!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
//        logDir(context.getCacheDir());
//        logDir(dir);

    return dir;
}

@Nullable
public static File generateFileName(@Nullable String name, File directory) {
    if (name == null) {
        return null;
    }

    File file = new File(directory, name);

    if (file.exists()) {
        String fileName = name;
        String extension = "";
        int dotIndex = name.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (dotIndex > 0) {
            fileName = name.substring(0, dotIndex);
            extension = name.substring(dotIndex);
        }

        int index = 0;

        while (file.exists()) {
            index++;
            name = fileName + '(' + index + ')' + extension;
            file = new File(directory, name);
        }
    }

    try {
        if (!file.createNewFile()) {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.w(TAG, e);
        return null;
    }

    //logDir(directory);

    return file;
}

private static void saveFileFromUri(Context context, Uri uri, String destinationPath) {
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        is = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(destinationPath, false));
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        is.read(buf);
        do {
            bos.write(buf);
        } while (is.read(buf) != -1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (is != null) is.close();
            if (bos != null) bos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciated the help on this [thread](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/issues/101#issuecomment-438949085)

Answer (score -2):

```
@Override

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == SELECT_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {getApplicationContext();
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {



            if(data == null){
                //no data present
                return;
            }


            Uri selectedFileUri = data.getData();
            fPath= FilePath.getPath(this,selectedFileUri);
            Log.i(TAG, "Selected File Path:" + fPath);

            if(fPath!= null && !fPath.equals("")){
                tv.setText(fPath);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this,"Cannot upload file to server",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }







            tv.setText(fPath);

        } else {
            // failed to select file
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to select file", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```